# How to access a Django method from Angular 7

Tags: django, angular, httprequest, httpclient, angular7

Im pretty new to full stack development so this might actually be an easy question:

I want to be able to access a simple method in the **models.py** file of my Django backend:

```
def testMethodFromModelPY(request, path=''):

    data = {'returnedData': 'whatever'}
    return data
```

I add the path to the method in **urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path
from DjangoBackEnd import models

urlpatterns = [
    # some other paths here that frontend is able to access #
    path(r'api/v1/', models.testMethodFromModelPY, name='testMethodFromModelPY'),
]
```

Now, within Angular frontend I create a component called config in the app folder and add to **config.service.ts**

```
export interface Test {
    returnedData: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  testMethodInConfigServiceTS() {
    return this.http.get('/api/v1/testMethodFromModelPY/');
  }
}
```

I include this Service in **app.module.ts** and call the **testMethodInConfigServiceTS** function in **config.component.ts**:

```
testMethodInConfigComponentTS() {
    this.configService.testMethodInConfigServiceTS()
      .subscribe(
        (data: Test) => this.test = { ...data }, // success path
        error => this.error = error // error path
      );
  }
```

Within **config.component.html** I try to access this method with:

```
<button (click)="testMethodInConfigComponentTS()">teststuffhere</button>
```

But when I clic a button I get the errormessage:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/testMethodFromModelPY/ 404 (Not Found)
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you're looking for is `angular -> url -> view -> model` but you seem to be missing the view in your logic.

Let's break it down.

1. Add a view to your django application. Django views are functions and/or classes that allow you to handle http requests. They're called by your `urls`. You can read more about them [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/). For example your view may look something like this:

   ```
   from django.http import HttpResponse
   from DjangoBackEnd import models

   def test_view(request):
       output = models.testMethodFromModelPY()
       return HttpResponse(output)
   ```
2. Map your views in your urls file.

   ```
   from django.urls import path
   from .views import test_view

   urlpatterns = [
       # some other paths here that frontend is able to access #
       path(r'api/v1/', test_view, name='testMethodFromModelPY'),
   ]
   ```

This will now allow you to hit `example-domain.com/api/v1/` which should provide you with the output of your test function in your models. Notice that I haven't added the name of the url aka `name='testMethodFromModelPY'` as this is used as reference in your templates Jinja code and Djangos internals. You can read more about urls [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/).

Saying that you'll have to amend your endpoint from:

```
testMethodInConfigServiceTS() {
  return this.http.get('/api/v1/testMethodFromModelPY/');
}
```

to

```
testMethodInConfigServiceTS() {
  return this.http.get('/api/v1/');
}
```

Take a look at [djangorestframework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) which is a great toolbox for api driven applications with a django backend.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Make an API and send some requests with angular

Django Rest Framework is easy and fast to set up
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/